# MySQL - Retrieve data from database by joining 3 tables and display one column value with comma

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables, named `location` and `Hospital` and `hospital location`. These are the fields and data of both table

**Table : location**

```
id | location_name
1  | location1
2  | location2
```

**Table : hospital**

```
id | hospital_name
1  | Hospital1
2  | Hospital2
```

**Table : hospital_location**

```
id | hospital_id | location_id
1  | 1          |   1
2  | 1          |   2
```

I need to create a query in mysql to display all the data from hospital table. The location_name column has multiple values, separated by a comma.

```
id | hospital_name | location_name
1  | Hospital1     | location1, location2
```

Comment: *"I need to create table in php"* - an "HTML" table?

Comment: Unclear. You should add more details about what you tried, how you have this error message, what's your code, etc. We will be able to help you from these informations.

Comment: YOU need to create table in php ___So you do it___. Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: read up on JOINS if you don't know how to query those

Comment: @RiggsFolly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQR1aCBW794

Comment: @juergend *lmho!* - df though lol?

Comment: Oh, not that important. I just found it funny that you used a similar expression in your comment like the one does in the video. Never mind...

Comment: looks like homework? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the GROUP_CONCAT mysql function
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
SELECT h.hospital_name, GROUP_CONCAT(l.location_name) as location_name
FROM hospital h
LEFT JOIN hospital_location hl ON hl.hospital_id = h.id
LEFT JOIN location.l ON hl.location_id = l.id
GROUP BY h.id
```

Comment: Thanks @dimitri-l.... You are a rock star for me..